# Telerik DelegateCommand Usage in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik, icommand

I'm a little stuck on the proper usage of `Telerik.Windows.Controls DelegateCommand`

I have the below set up, which compiles, however I am more concerned with, whether, I am using it correctly.  I have searched the Online Doc for a while now and couldn't find any examples.

Particularly, I am confused as how I would use the `CanSaveAuthorization`, or the underlying `CanExecute`, and what I would do with the object parameter that is required.

Thanks,

```
    public class CreateAuthorizationViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Authorization authorization;
        private AuthorizationRepository authorizationRepository;
        private DelegateCommand saveAuthorizationCommand;

        public DelegateCommand SaveAuthorizationCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return saveAuthorizationCommand;
            }
        }

        public CreateAuthorizationViewModel()
        {
            InitializeCommand(); 
        }

        private void InitializeCommand()
        {
            saveAuthorizationCommand = new DelegateCommand(SaveAuthorization, CanSaveAuthorization);           
        }

        private void SaveAuthorization(object parameter)
        {
            authorizationRepository.Save();
        }

        private bool CanSaveAuthorization(object parameter)
        {
            //I would have validation logic here
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `DelegateCommand` implements the `ICommand` interface. This means it can be bound to the Command property of a WPF control like `Button`. The CanExecute method (CanSaveAuthorization in your case) can eveluate whether the Execute method (SaveAuthorization in your case) may be allowed to execute, if not then the button will be disabled in the view. The parameter of type `object` may be of help here. I have never worked with Telerik's implementation but I think this is the value of the control's `CommandParameter` property that can be set in the view. If you have a CanExecute method that always returns true then you may as well remove it alltogether.

You may find more information and examples if you google for `RelayCommand`. This presumably is the pattern that Telerik based there `DelegateCommand` on. My version of the `DelegateCommand` has an overload without the `parameter` parameter. The CanExecute method then needs the information available in the viewmodel to determine the CanExecute state.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an aside, but you can get rid of the need for the InitializeCommand function:

```
public DelegateCommand SaveAuthorizationCommand
{
    get
    {
        return saveAuthorizationCommand ??
               (saveAuthorizationCommand = new DelegateCommand(SaveAuthorization, CanSaveAuthorization));
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, this won't compile, by the by.  It gives a `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer`

Comment: I think it's a good practice - you create the command the first time someone requests it.  Try the updated code sample - I forgot () around the assignment.